# How do you subscribe and assign subscriber to group with the mailchimp api?

Tags: php, mailchimp

I am attempting to use the API in PHP to subscribe and assign a subscriber to a group.

I need to be able to create the group on the fly and I'm trying something like the following with not much success:

```
// include other relevant files here

$merge_vars = array(
   'FNAME'=>$name[0],
   'LNAME'=>$name[1], 
   'INTERESTS'=>'',
   'GROUPINGS'=>'Pets'
 );
```

If I remove the 'groupings' from the Array, the subscribing works just fine - so we've got that going... but how do we do groups?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little late, but I figured this might help someone else.

```
$merge_vars = array(
    'GROUPINGS' => array(
        0 => array(
            'id' => "101", //You have to find the number via the API
            'groups' => "Interest Name 1, Interest Name 2",
        )
    )
);
```

And then you can use the `listUpdateMember()` method to add an existing subscriber to an interest group.

```
// Then use listUpdateMember to add them
$objMailChimp->listUpdateMember($listID, $email, $merge_vars));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 1 more thing in array i.e  "EMAIL" => "test@test.com"

& when you calling listSubscribe() check your

apiKey, listId,

"email id which is to be add in subscriber list comes here i.e test@test.com", 
EMAIL_TYPE fields properly.

try this. It will be helpful for you.